# Typescript loop through all HTML select <option>

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to learn TypeScript and Angular. I have an HTML with a lot of option inside, I need to populate an array inside ts file with all of that option. I have done something like this:

```
initializeItems() {
 var select = document.getElementById("idOfSelect");
 for (var i = 0; i <= select.length; i++ )
```

but obiouvsly, `select.lenght` couldn't work. What can I do?

Comment: Please include your Angular HTML template as well. I'm  quite sure there is an *Angular* way of doing this instead of vanilla javascript :)

Comment: you can use an *ngfor on the option tag.

Comment: What is in your `select` variable? provide its value.

Answer (score 0):

Forget document.getElementBy...

The Angular way is to use [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

This way you can write something like this:

```
@ViewChildren('idOfSelect') selectedElements: QueryList<any>;
```

then `selectedElements.length` and `selectedElements.forEach(...)` will work.

Comment: Good idea, poor execution.